# PHP If statement displaying incorrect results

Tags: php

I am running this PHP Code:

```
$earliest='2013-11-19 23:00:00';
$latest='2013-11-19 01:00:00';

if(isset($earliest) and isset($latest))
{
    if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") >= $earliest and date("Y-m-d H:i:s") <= $latest)
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

the current date/time (2013-11-19 12:52:00) is > or = to the $earliest variable but its displaying no

any ideas why this would be? have i done something wrong in my code?

if i do just:

```
if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") <= $latest)
```

it displays yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your earliest is actually after your latest (11pm vs 1am)

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operators are incorrect:

```
 if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") >= $earliest and date("Y-m-d H:i:s") <= $latest)
```

should be:

```
 if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") >= $earliest && date("Y-m-d H:i:s") <= $latest)
```